# Is this the correct way of using a void* member pointer?

Tags: c++

Can I use the method doSomething like this; first having assigned the pointer to the A class to the void* member of b?

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int);
        int m_x;
        int doSomething(){};
};

class B
{
    public:
        void* m_y;
};

#include "x.h"
using namespace std;

A::A(int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}

int main()
{
    //create 2 pointers to A and B
    B *b;
    A *a;

    b = new B();
    a = new A(15);

    b->m_y =  a;        

    ((A*)b->m_y)->doSomething();

    delete a;
    delete b;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can, but why should you throw away typing and force yourself to cast *everywhere*, opening up the possibility of undefined behaviour basically everywhere you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stay away from `void*`

Why not have a pointer to `A` in `B` (or even, `B` owns the instance of `A`), or `B` holds a smart pointer to an instance of `A` - there are so many other *better* ways of doing things.

Comment: I don't control the class definition of B, that's why I cannot use a pointer to A or a smart pointer.

Comment: ..hmm.. if it is completely outside of your control (say some thirdparty thing) - then the `reinterpret_cast` cannot be avoided - if it's someone else in your company (group, etc.) - go round there with a cricket bat (not that I'm enticing violence mind you!) ;)

Comment: :) Thanks, I might bring it up, but not with a cricket bat ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, although you should not use C-style casts. Better use `static_cast`:

```
(static_cast<A*>(b->m_y))->doSomething();
```

Comment: noooo.. don't recommend anything like this to someone who appears to be a beginner...

Comment: @Nim: My first reaction was to say what the same thing as the other answers, but then, for some reason I decided to post this - don't know what happened there.

Comment: Even though static_cast from void* works quite fine here, I would recommend a reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast. Reinterpret_cast is a sign that something fishy is going on.  Going through void* is always fishy. That reinterpret_cast is a nice signpost to leave for future maintainers.

Comment: @Nim: You prefer a C-style cast to an explicit cast? Why? Our project, for example, makes C-style casts illegal (and the compiler can check for them.) If reinterpret_cast is evil, which it oftentimes is, C-style casts are evil incarnate. In my opinion of course.

Comment: @David, I prefer not to use `void*` period. IFF you have to use it, then my preference is for `reinterpret_cast` too...

Comment: @Nim: From the comments to your post, the use of void* is not under the OP's control.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is technically correct, but it's also quite useless.

If you know you'll be storing an `A*` in `m_y`, then why not give it that type? If you don't know ahead of time what exact type you'll be storing, use inheritance and polymorphism (`virtual`), which is *much* safer.

**EDIT**: okay, this is interfacing to legacy code. Then `static_cast` is the cleanest, most explicit way to do the cast. It's entirely equivalent to what you're doing, however.

Comment: "the mapping performed by reinterpret_cast is implementation-defined." [5.2.10.3]. Use static_cast for converting from `void*` to its original/compatable pointer type. This is well-defined by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no correct way to use a `void*` pointer.

Comment: While I understand the sentiment, this is not an answer to the question. There is sometimes a need to use `void*`, when interfacing to legacy code.

Comment: +1, to counteract, "No" is the correct answer, and the last bit is additional sentiment - which is also true.

Comment: No correct way? What about `operator new` and `operator delete` ?

Comment: -1: There are correct ways to use `void*`. The standard defines legal and correct ways to use it.